# how to find out which tcp congestion control my os is using

Tags: tcp, wireshark, congestion-control

I would like to find out which congestion control algorithm my computer is using.
I know I can google it, but I want to find out by experimenting.
My first step was to run wireshark when I downloaded a big file.
Then I tried the IO Graph and got the following: [image: io graph from wireshark]

Is this graph typical for any congestion control algorithm? I can't see any specific behavior - I know the following algorithms: Tahoe, Reno/NewReno and Cubic.

Is there a better way to find out which algorithm my computer is using?

Answer (score 1):

See my answer at [Is there an algorithm for fingerprinting the TCP congestion control algorithm used in a captured session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528733/is-there-an-algorithm-for-fingerprinting-the-tcp-congestion-control-algorithm-us/705393#705393)

The IO graph will show the bandwidth achieved and that's not very useful. To say much you'll need to look at the sequence number graph and see if there are discernible patterns in it.